# Is there a simpler way to assign a dictionary and loop through to update?

Tags: python, dictionary

Tried to just loop through each key appending it to a list, then loop through it, but it failed.  Was wondering if there was a nicer way of updating my dictionary instead of defining all those variables above and updating it one-by-one?

```
nfl = dict()
nfl['Tom'] = tom = dict()
nfl['bob'] = bob = dict()
nfl['kara'] = kara = dict()
nfl['Mike'] = mike = dict()

for k in data:
    if 'tom_score' in data[k]:
        <doing stuff here>
    elif 'bob'in k:
        bob.update(data[k])
    elif 'kara'in k:
        kara.update(data[k])
    elif 'mike'in k:
        mike.update(data[k])
```

Comment: I dont really get the question, how does data looks like? What dou you need `tom` for, if you can acces it with `nfl['Tom']`?

Comment: I'm initially reading through +2 files. Modifying the first key and saving that off as it's own key. Then taking the other keys, adding/updating them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a typo and `'Tom'` and `'tom_score'` supposed to be the same, you can use `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

nfl = defaultdict(dict)

for k in data:
    if k in ['Tom', 'bob', 'kara', 'Mike']:
        nfl[k].update(data[k])
```

You can skip `if` part with names check if you want to have all names from the `data` and not only specified ones.

Comment: Thanks for the help Yaroslav.